# Accessing Windows 'tags' metadata field of an image

Tags: windows, image, matlab, image-processing

I ma trying to put hands on some image processing. So for now what i am trying is to read image exif data. Well there are 2 built-in functions are available for reading exif data of an image.
The problem is that i want to read image tags.`exifread` and `imfinfo` both of these functions do not show image tags.

Is there any way to read image tags ? Like the tags are highlighted in this picture
[image: Like the tags are highlighted in this picture]

Comment: i have tried it to upload it here but it is about 15mb and i am getting an error on uploading it here.

Comment: @Jigg i will share it via dropbox link

Comment: @Jigg here is the link 
[Image link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cj6u2azitwlax8/tekapo-new-zealand-trey-ratcliff-2.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: i already mentioned that `imfinfo` is not providing me the solution for that

Comment: All right, I don't see the rating in the metadata, I'm editing your question to make it more precise.

Comment: thank you for that :) 
plus i am new to matlab.i have read about something about exiftool.
i tried it too but its something above then my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Steps:

1. Download exiftool. I found one after googling and I don't want to put up external links here, but this I can say as a pointer that the site reads -
   "ExifTool by Phil Harvey". Get the zip setup file from there, extract the exe from it and put it in the current working directory of MATLAB.
2. Download getexif.m frrom [MATLAB FEX](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42000-run-exiftool/content/run_exiftool/getexif.m) and also save it in the current
   working directory.

Now, you can run this MATLAB code and get the tag info -

```
%//Get image exif info as a char array
exif_data = getexif(path_to_image_file)

%// Split the char array into cells, where each cell holds both the field
%// and its value
exif_data_c = strsplit(exif_data,'\n')

%// Split each cell into its field and value
iminfo_fv_splt = strtrim(cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,':'),exif_data_c,'uni',0))

%// Look for the field "Subject" and store it as this field appears to store tag info
subj = iminfo_fv_splt(cellfun(@(x,n) strcmp(x(1),'Subject'),iminfo_fv_splt))

%// Select the second cell that corresponds to the value of the field
tag_found = subj{1}(2)
```

Output -

```
tag_found = 
    'New Zealand, Trey, lake tekapo, ratcliff, stuckincustoms, stuckincustoms.com, trey ratcliff'
```

Comment: @divikar i am facing one more problem in the statement `tag_found = subj{1}(2)`. it is saying that "Reference to non-existent element of a cell array."

Comment: @AqeelAbbas Can you manually check if there is a tag. That error means there is no tag there.

Comment: @divikar there are tags with associated with subject title. i have checked that in file.i really would like to save all those tags into a varible

Comment: @AqeelAbbas Are you talking about the image that you have linked in the comments to your question or is it some other image?

Comment: @divikar i am doing it on the same image

Comment: @AqeelAbbas That dropbox link was too slow for me. Could you download [**this one**](http://i3.minus.com/ibuCNTFHeSnp1r.jpg) and try instead? It seems like the same image.

Comment: Well i am still having the same error :( 
i downloaded it from the link you gave me.

Comment: @AqeelAbbas Did you rename the exe to exiftool.exe? If not, you must do it and then try again.

Comment: i did bro. when i show all the exif data like `[exifdata1, nf1] = getexif([p,f]);` it shows every thing in there.+ also the subject part too. p is path and f is file

Comment: @AqeelAbbas Could you copy and paste output of - `exif_data_c'` into pastebin.com and link it here?

Comment: i got it running :) 
thank you bro for all that effort, actually the problem is with `exif_data_c` it is not pointing to the targeted thing.i got it fixed :)

Comment: @AqeelAbbas what targeted thing? Did you put a wrong path?

Comment: no! i have tried to output the contents of it on command window and it shows some string like unable to open.....

Comment: i have used this `[exifdata, nf1] = getexif([p,f]);
` to read exifdata and it solved the problem.i guess this `exif_data = getexif(p);` might not be able of open the file.so may be that is why i am having no outputs.