# Accessing 'tags' metadata field of an image using c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, tags, metadata

I am working on images to rank them. Initially i made up a data set to store image meta data into it. I ran into a problem when i have to extract meta data of images. I am able to extract all of the meta data except the "tags" field which i need to rank images.

I am attaching the link to similar post but it is in matlab.
[Extracting meta data "tags field"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125877/accessing-windows-tags-metadata-field-of-an-image)

I only need the information which is encircled in red.

Comment: How are you extracting the meta data? Show us that code and we might be able to help a bit easier

Comment: I have followed this code. [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231165-how-to-read-image-metadata-in-c%23/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply put by means of meme: "One does not simply extract tag metadata", apparently.

From what I have discovered, the Tag metadata that gets set when on the properties page of a JPG, from within Explorer, is relatively easy to get.
They are in the `PropertyItem` with ID `9C9E` (or `40094` in Decimal).
This `PropertyItem`'s Value is a `byte[]` with Unicode characters and is null terminated.

Below is a method to extract the tag ( `;` seperated, so you can adjust the method to return a list of them split up if you want)

```
private string ReadBasicTags(string filename)
{
  string foundTags = string.Empty;

  using (Image inputImage = new Bitmap(filename))
  {
    try
    {
      PropertyItem basicTag = inputImage.GetPropertyItem(40094); // Hex 9C9E
      if (basicTag != null)
      {
        foundTags = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(basicTag.Value).Replace("\0", string.Empty);
      }
    }
    // ArgumentException is thrown when GetPropertyItem(int) is not found
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
      // finalOutput = "Tags not found";
    }
  }

  return foundTags;
}
```

With this [sample image](http://s12.postimg.org/6xhoah2al/SOTag_Demo.jpg) you should get a string output of

> TagOne;TagTwo:

*However* you may have noticed that I am talking about basic Tag information and Tags that set in Windows Explorer itself. They are easy to get.
If you where to run the above code on either [this sample](http://metadatadeluxe.pbworks.com/f/example027.jpg) or [this sample](http://metadatadeluxe.pbworks.com/f/1242531528/GettyVillaExifToolImport.JPG), you would not get any data back. This is because of the massive amount of different ways that metadata can be stored inside a jpeg by all the various tools and hardware.
If you want to have an idea of how many different types of metadata and all the different names of the tags and their formats, head on over to the [ExifTool by Phil Harvey](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), explore a bit on that page, especially the "Tag Names" page and you are sure to get a headache of the sheer amount of different tags.

Now you are probably wondering if you should even delve deeper into the world of metadata tag extraction or if you could make a wrapper for that tool to integrate it into C# (which apparently some have done, but requires the tool to be present and other things, check under the [Additional Resources](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#links) section of the tool's page for info).

Ah, but fear not! For someone has figured out a simpler way, in C#, to extract the right information so that you can use the metadata tags alone.
I found this little [GitHub project (JpegMetadata by Marcel Wijnands)](https://github.com/mwijnands/JpegMetadata) while trying to wrap my head around the enormousy that is exif metadata.  This little library makes it easy for you to extract the metadata tag and works on all the samples that I have linked so far.
You can install it into your project with NuGet if you are using VisualStudio.

The resulting `List<string>` that you get when calling the library gives you each tag separately.

As examples, the image [Arena Chapel frescoes](http://metadatadeluxe.pbworks.com/w/page/34966212/VRA_beta_example_027) (example027.jpg) and [Getty Villa](http://metadatadeluxe.pbworks.com/w/page/20792236/ExifTool%20import%20function%2C%20jpeg) (GettyVilla0001.JPG) produce the below lists with the shown code:

```
  JpegMetadataAdapter metaAdapter = new JpegMetadataAdapter(@"C:\Dev\example027.JPG");

  foreach (string item in metaAdapter.Metadata.Keywords)
  {
    outputString += string.Format("{0}{1}", item, Environment.NewLine);
  }
```

> Medieval
>   Italian
>   paintings (visual works)
>   frescoes (paintings)
>   fresco painting (technique)
>   allegorical
>   architectural interiors
>   cycles or series
>   New Testament
>   Old Testament and Apocrypha
>   saints
>   Jesus Christ
>   Mary, Blessed Virgin
>   Saint
>   Christian iconography
>   the Passion
>   Judas Iscariot
>   disciples

```
  JpegMetadataAdapter metaAdapter = new JpegMetadataAdapter(@"C:\Dev\GettyVilla0001.JPG");

  foreach (string item in metaAdapter.Metadata.Keywords)
  {
    outputString += string.Format("{0}{1}", item, Environment.NewLine);
  }
```

> sunset
>   shadows
>   mural painting
>   peristyles (colonnades)
>   trompe-l'oeil
>   greek
>   roman
>   Getty Villa

Both of these images store their metadata tags differently, so it is fair to say that with that library you should be covered by most of the versions of the metadata tags in *jpegs*.

Comment: This link provides a great way to see all metadata in case you don't want to use custom libraries: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66328/Enumerating-all-of-the-Metadata-Tags-in-an-Image-F