# Setting tags in .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, tags

I have tried various methods of setting the Windows Tags field on multiple JPEG files in a C# .Net Framework 4.7.2 project and code methods such as

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;

var shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(sFile);
string[] sTags = sTagString.Split(';');
shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.AllowSetTruncatedValue = true;
shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.Value = sTags;
shellFile.Dispose();
```

but this code crashes with the untrapped error 'Unable to get writable property store for this property' after a variable number of files are processed. Using the FotoFly dll gives another untrapped error.

If I place the ShellFile code in a separate executable which is run for each image I can achieve the desired result but processing is very slow. Is there a way of reliably setting JPEG file tag metadata from code for multiple files?

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748356/accessing-tags-metadata-field-of-an-image-using-c-sharp